# Condensing multiple for-loops to a simpler for-loop to assign values in a data frame that exist in another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am looking to simplify my for-loops into one for-loop for this particular data question.

Here is my original data frame that I would like to edit:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id=c('bird1','bird2','bird3','bird4','bird5','bird6','bird7'),Sex=c('M','M','F','F','F','F','F'),YR05=c(1,0,3,1,1,1,1),YR06=c(0,1,0,0,2,0,3),'mass05_1'=c(1,0,3,1,1,1,1), 'mass05_2'=c(1,0,3,1,1,1,1),'mass05_3'=c(1,0,3,1,1,1,1),'mass06_1'=c(0,1,0,0,2,0,3),'mass06_2'=c(0,1,0,0,2,0,3),'mass06_3'=c(0,1,0,0,2,0,3),stringsAsFactors=T)

   Id    Sex YR05 YR06 mass05_1 mass05_2 mass05_3 mass06_1 mass06_2 mass06_3
1 bird1   M    1    0        1        1        1        0        0        0
2 bird2   M    0    1        0        0        0        1        1        1
3 bird3   F    3    0        3        3        3        0        0        0
4 bird4   F    1    0        1        1        1        0        0        0
5 bird5   F    1    2        1        1        1        2        2        2
6 bird6   F    1    0        1        1        1        0        0        0
7 bird7   F    1    3        1        1        1        3        3        3
```

Each bird was re-sighted in either site 1,2 or 3 for years 2005 and 2006. I need to attach the average mass of birds at each site per year for each bird according to where it was re-sighted, hence the replicated mass columns.

I am using this data frame to gather the masses:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Year=c('YR05','YR06','YR05','YR06','YR05','YR06'),Site=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),Mass=c(743,735,658,620,542,556))

  Year Site Mass
1 YR05    1  743
2 YR06    1  735
3 YR05    2  658
4 YR06    2  620
5 YR05    3  542
6 YR06    3  556
```

And finally this is my desired output:

```
output <- data.frame(Id=c('bird1','bird2','bird3','bird4','bird5','bird6','bird7'),Sex=c('M','M','F','F','F','F','F'),YR05=c(1,0,3,1,1,1,1),YR06=c(0,1,0,0,2,0,3),'mass05_1'=c(743,0,0,743,743,743,743), 'mass05_2'=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),'mass05_3'=c(0,0,542,0,0,0,0),'mass06_1'=c(0,735,0,0,0,0,0),'mass06_2'=c(0,0,0,0,620,0,0),'mass06_3'=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,556),stringsAsFactors=T)

     Id Sex YR05 YR06 mass05_1 mass05_2 mass05_3 mass06_1 mass06_2 mass06_3
1 bird1   M    1    0      743        0        0        0        0        0
2 bird2   M    0    1        0        0        0      735        0        0
3 bird3   F    3    0        0        0      542        0        0        0
4 bird4   F    1    0      743        0        0        0        0        0
5 bird5   F    1    2      743        0        0        0      620        0
6 bird6   F    1    0      743        0        0        0        0        0
7 bird7   F    1    3      743        0        0        0        0      556
```

I did these for-loops over each column:

```
for (i in 5){
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %nin% 1)] <- 0
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %in% 1)] <- 743
}

for (i in 6){
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %nin% 2)] <- 0
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %in% 2)] <- 658
}

for (i in 7){
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %nin% 3)] <- 0
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %in% 3)] <- 542
}

for (i in 8){
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %nin% 1)] <- 0
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %in% 1)] <- 735
}

for (i in 9){
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %nin% 2)] <- 0
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %in% 2)] <- 620
}

for (i in 10){
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %nin% 3)] <- 0
  df1[,i][which(df1[,i] %in% 3)] <- 556
}
```

This gives me my desired result BUT I am not sure how to condense these loops into one for-loop, I have over 200 columns that span many years in my dataset so doing this column by column will not work. I will need a more general for-loop to edit the data.

Comment: Have you considered taking a reshaping approach?  If you converted your original dataset into a format more like `df2` (a *longer* format) you could then use joins to merge the datasets.  You could convert things back to a wide format in the end, if you need it in the wider format for some sort of analysis or something.

Comment: If I were to use the melt function to reshape my original data into long format, what would my id.vars be? melt(df1, id.vars = c(...,...)). I would imagine it would have to be by site to match the likes of df2 but my dataset doesn't contain a site column, that site indicator is in the column names.

Comment: I haven't used `melt()` in ages ;-D but I'm picturing you want info in the "mass" columns gathered together so all others would be ID (maybe).  Once all those "mass" column names are in a single column you could make new columns (one for year, one for site) by extracting the info from those original column names.  These would then be the ID variables you could merge on.

Comment: Do you known bird id for `df2`?